# Product tab data is not save in database in magento admin

Tags: php, magento

I have created costume tab it called "Customizer Settings" edit product page in admin.

I have created Observer Model with below code

```
<?php

class ProductCustomizer_ProductCustomize_Model_Observer
{

    static protected $_singletonFlag = false;

    public function saveProductTabData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if (!self::$_singletonFlag) {
            self::$_singletonFlag = true;

            $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
            print_r($product);
            try {

                $customFieldValue =  $this->_getRequest()->getPost('productcustomizer');

                $product->productcustomizer = $customFieldValue

                /*foreach ($customFieldValue as $key => $value) {
                    $product->$key =  $value;
                }*/

                $product->save();
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Value is not saved in database and nothing printing in ajax.

Could you please let me know how to display saved value in ".phtml" file I have added below code in .phtml file.

```
<tr>
    <td class="label">
        <label for="productcustomizer_enable">Enable</label>
    </td>
    <td class="value">
        <label> <input type="checkbox"  name="productcustomizer[enable]" id="productcustomizer_enable" />  Enable customizer</label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="label">
        <label for="productcustomizer_price">Customization Price</label>
    </td>
    <td class="value">
        <input type="text"  class="input-text" name="productcustomizer[customization_price]" id="productcustomizer_price" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Why you are not using the catalog attributes?

Comment: Because I want set product customization base from here.

Comment: Your requirement is basic and can be done by attributes only.

Comment: Do you have any other way for save value?

Comment: I have found solution, Please check below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41342852/custom-tab-data-is-not-save-in-product-edit-in-magento-admin