# Custom tab data is not save in product edit in magento admin

Tags: php, magento

I have created a custom tab in Magento but while saving the product data is not reflected in database.

I have created below from with input field.

```
<div class="input-field">
    <label for="custom_field">Custom Field</label>
    <input class="input-text" name="custom_field" id="custom_field" />
</div>
```

I have wrote below code in Observer.

```
public function saveProductTabData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    if (!self::$_singletonFlag) {
        self::$_singletonFlag = true;   
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        try {
            $customFieldValue =  $this->_getRequest()->getPost('custom_field');
            $product->setNewAttribute($customFieldValue); 
            #$product->custom_field = $customFieldValue;
            $product->save();
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I have followed all steps of this site https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/custom-tabs-magento-product-admin/

Comment: try this $product->setCustomField("value");

Comment: I have tried this code `$product->setCustomField($customFieldValue);` but it is not working.

Comment: Please set store id to admin store id. That is
Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(0);

And also the custom field value to the product object, like  
$product->setCustomField($customFieldValue)

Comment: How to use this? Do you mean add this code in Observer before `$product->setCustomField("value")`?

Comment: have you checked your observer is calling.. and have you created product attribute

Comment: Yes Observer file is calling, I have printed this line `$this->_getRequest()->getPost('custom_field')`.

Comment: And also I have checked log file but nothing logged in log file.

Comment: Have you created product attribute with code custom_field

Comment: Yes I have created

Comment: use $product = $observer->getProduct(); this instead of  $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct(); and check Mage::log($product->getId()); in your log file

Comment: Ok, I have changed code but it is not working nothing saved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131579/discussion-between-faizanbeg-and-chetan-khandla).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'custom_field', array(
'entity_model' => 'catalog/product',
'label' => 'custom',
'group' => 'General',
'input' => 'text',
'type' => 'text',
'is_html_allowed_on_front' => false,
'backend' => 'catalog/product_attribute_backend_price',
'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
'visible' => false,
'apply_to' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE,
'required' => false,
'user_defined' => true,
'unique' => false,
'visible_on_front' => false,
'note' => 'custom'
));

use this function in tab.php block
public function getProduct()
{
return Mage::registry('product');
}
```